# Google Earth Engine print result for a collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the next code and I would like to print the pixel value summarize of "surf_refl_01" for all the collection instead to do it one image by one.

Is it possible?

The code:

```js
// Region of interest
var region = table2;

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13Q1')
.filterDate('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31')
.filterBounds(table2);

print(collection);

var image1 = ee.Image('MODIS/MOD13Q1/MOD13Q1_005_2000_02_18');

var clip = image1.clip(region);

var sumB3 = clip.select('sur_refl_b01').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: table2,
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

var sumB4 = clip.select('sur_refl_b02').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: table2,
  scale: 250,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

Map.addLayer(clip);

print(sumB3)
print(sumB4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweak Tyler's code a little bit..

```js
// Region of interest
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-105.34, 40.08],
          [-105.34, 39.95],
          [-105.20, 39.95],
          [-105.20, 40.08]]]);

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13Q1')
                   .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31')
                   .filterBounds(region);

var ComputeRegionMean = function(img, list) {
  list = ee.List(list)
  var date = img.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
  var region_mean = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 250,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return list.add(ee.List([date, region_mean.get('sur_refl_b03')]));
};

ee.Dictionary(collection.iterate(ComputeRegionMean, ee.List([])))
var image_stats = ee.List(collection.iterate(ComputeRegionMean, ee.List([])))
var image_stats = ee.Dictionary(image_stats.flatten())
print(image_stats)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can map a function across your collection that saves the region-of-interest statistic as an image property. You then can use [ee.ImageCollection.aggregate_array()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagecollectionaggregate_array) to convert it to a printable object.

```js
// Region of interest
var region = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-105.34, 40.08],
          [-105.34, 39.95],
          [-105.20, 39.95],
          [-105.20, 40.08]]]);

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/MOD13Q1')
                   .filterDate('2000-01-01', '2017-12-31')
                   .filterBounds(region);

var ComputeRegionMean = function(img) {
  var region_mean = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: region,
    scale: 250,
    maxPixels: 1e9
  });
  return img.set(region_mean);
};

var image_with_stats = collection.map(ComputeRegionMean);

print(image_with_stats.aggregate_array("sur_refl_b03"));
```